# Remembering VST presets in Max/Msp

Tags: audio, vst, max-msp-jitter

I am trying to get Max/MSP to remember vst presets for my patch. Every time I close the patch and re-open, the vst goes to default. The vst I am trying to use is called alchemy (free version). Does anyone know how to get max/msp to remember vst presets, does it vary for different vst's and audio unit plugins? Here is the link to download alchemy player.
http://www.camelaudio.com/AlchemyPlayer.php

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.

Comment: On the contrary, Max/MSP is a programming language. To solve his problem it is necessary to do some coding in Max (see answer), so I believe this question fits here just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to

- get the vst~ object to list all its parameters,
- get their values,
- store them in a coll and save that coll to disk,

like so:

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
811.3ocyWtrbaBCEFdM9ofgt00CRb0sq5KP2zkc53Q1n5nLXAUR33lLoO6U5
HHgbwDriJ0K.acj.8qOet46l4Ert5.UF3+I+u664c2LOOvjwfW6XufcjCaJI
RXYAb5MUquNXtcJE8fBLWKn0Tdg+MBlh1M6Oq3JI6VpYEH7hvVyUMpRpR86Z
pciCB7+Q6T0D0lqX7sqDzMJ6rnjk5mzGmEa9HOBFDtH7gmgU.JPqpOhy5u0b
xNXGB9hfQJ6lg2riw06ObbPOZzpJqUiw6mMyba96iKRxdZgd2q1dxPYt8ZMg
ucL.JNwbOMeP9j5D9D4N9n7K8WeNnYrXIK0bOBuHY.rj3DrfOCrX.w5Fkphe
t9GLtpGGDTIkqHJVEuOKRiVfSyhSR0dHfeRX6sQPPDD3gBCGzyJ9LQXMQnWr
hJVQ4j0kviE9bujuoihBblq3NpTR1ReguXkNC16H00qidbL3.hv4iE63TD7D
HXwQYvf7if8nSD6Xmkv6XTrtrYqSK.fwPvaGOhFjG3+a73HI31TUVdtg1v0f
nw5b0VaTGtNTRtPmjjKt0JTXak9EqEyJhRIX5zX1VI7dfPdAzcqofFBAC.Sc
DY6Z4PppDtskiNrl.Ah4ICk3CEdo0xQGW1RUNlJ1J.XfGYCRkkWZPo4V1oBC
nCi4O94SKz9J7A01aJ30z5BcD9j6jzTNrOLg90R8+X7YkpZDTAkA0wRvCQkL
mPErCKloigNGnLXWUY8KmEiFpbVzkV0r8R0eNUZHYa4F81+alqRlT0EWM1Bd
cvy5Ggz9VCTwC4D5k2qfW6I5Ce0HTKKzmiJRQCm8qFpdu0c2oM8Y8gnGzAwo
Ou7m+WsgSnw9S+kPV0H1zsYccW6+3YrfJULNzoY+Ek9jEcEqnfx62NcASZ5v
9wxwuvmXz5IcL5IY5zS1XzS3zomjwnmroUOn2POQSmbhFAdPSlbzEi8wugZV
NcvAeQAGT3kUnU1H7jQSmbL+PD8FxY5hyWdQ45Lljx4SlZ9WlywVfmTWumJj
suRPH5lpttRXFlNGFx31gve3IPP2y5VucADgtkGktemFgsckC4oAyL6y8y9K
LRzZPA
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```

When loading the patch, you read the text file and send the parameter values to the vst~ object.

Hth

Answer (score 0):

The read & write messages to vst~ open dialog boxes you can save your effects files in.

In Max 5, Windows 7 64-bit, I had to write the following message to read a file directly:

(read C:/myvsts/presets/quiet.fxp)

Likewise there's the following vst~ messages to interact with saving:

- read
- write
- writepgm
- writebank

These are shown in the vst~ helpfile and further in the reference.